# Password field(s) not rendering in phpldapadmin

Tags: ldap, phpldapadmin

I tried setting up LDAP in a VM running on Ubuntu 14.04, and I also tried installing phpldapadmin. Now, I can access phpldapadmin, but when I try to create a new user account, it gives me this error:

> Error trying to get a non-existant value
>   (appearance,password_hash_custom)

I've tried the fix suggested [here](https://wiki.r00tedvw.com/index.php/Ubuntu/openldap). I've also tried searching stackoverflow, and I saw the same suggestion. Unfortunately, the error won't go away. It's as if it's looking for pre-existing values.

I followed the instructions provided [here](http://www.unixmen.com/install-openldap-in-ubuntu-15-10-and-debian-8/) in setting up LDAP and phpldapadmin. I'm now wondering if I've missed a step, like for example maybe I should've loaded a certain .ldif file or something.

Backtrace of the error gives this:

```
/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/functions.php (444)
    error (a:5:{i:0;s:74:"Error trying to get a non-existant ...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/ds.php (81)
    debug_dump_backtrace (a:2:{i:0;s:74:"Error trying to get a non-existant ...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php (986)
    getValue (a:2:{i:0;s:10:"appearance";i:1;s:20:"password_hash...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php ()
    drawFormReadWriteValuePasswordAttribute (a:2:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php (598)
    __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:18:"FormReadWri...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php (598)
    draw (a:3:{i:0;s:18:"FormReadWriteValue";i:1;O:17:"Passw...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/PageRender.php ()
    drawFormValueAttribute (a:2:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (2159)
    __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:9:"FormValue";i...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (2159)
    draw (a:3:{i:0;s:9:"FormValue";i:1;O:17:"PasswordAttribu...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php ()
    drawValueAttribute (a:2:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1828)
    __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:5:"Value";i:1;O...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1828)
    draw (a:3:{i:0;s:5:"Value";i:1;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php ()
    drawTemplateValuesAttribute (a:1:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1817)
    __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:14:"TemplateVal...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1817)
    draw (a:2:{i:0;s:14:"TemplateValues";i:1;O:17:"PasswordA...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php ()
    drawTemplateAttribute (a:1:{i:0;O:17:"PasswordAttribute":34:{s:4:"name";s...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/Visitor.php (58)
    call_user_func_array (a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;O:14:"TemplateRender":9:{s:24:"...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1602)
        __call (a:2:{i:0;s:4:"draw";i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:8:"Template";i:...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1602)
    draw (a:2:{i:0;s:8:"Template";i:1;O:17:"PasswordAttribut...)

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (1527)
    drawShownAttributes (a:0:{})

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (644)
    drawStepForm (a:1:{i:0;i:1;})

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php (84)
    visitEnd (a:0:{})

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/htdocs/template_engine.php (55)
    accept (a:0:{})

/usr/share/phpldapadmin/htdocs/cmd.php (60)
    include (a:1:{i:0;s:50:"/usr/share/phpldapadmin/htdocs/temp...)
```

I've been scanning the files, but I couldn't pinpoint the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additional information:
OpenLDAP version: 2.4
PHP version: 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried giving it another shot. I purged my ldap and phpldapadmin, and reinstalled them. Before, I also edited the functions.php and PageRender.php files in /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib (I saw this on another tutorial), aside from TemplateRender.php. This time, I only edited the TemplateRender.php file, and it worked.